# Moving Google Cloud Platform resources between projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have seen some old answers for this question but I was wondering if Google has added any feature to move resources between projects of the same organization. I would like to move compute engine and SQL resources and maintain the external IP address

Comment: Sorry, but you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move resources between Google Cloud Projects.

Most resources in Google Cloud are tied to the project's internal infrastructure. The primary issue is network addressing which is private to the Google Cloud Project. Google does not provide automated methods to move resources between projects.

You will have to backup and recreate/restore the resources in the new project. You will also have to assign new public Internet addresses.